# Use property value based on string

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, list, properties

I have a search filter that goes through the list of customers that I have, and depending on whether the string contains the value or not, returns the list that satisfies the condition. Right now it checks the company property in the condition, but I'd like it to be able to check any property that's given in the method (customerDetail is the property name in this function). How can I pass the string property and make it work with this statement?

```
If(oListOfCustomers.Item(iIndex).Company.ToString.Trim.Contains(sStringContains) = True) Then
```

For clarification, I want something along the lines of:

```
If(oListOfCustomers.Item(iIndex).customerDetail.ToString.Trim.Contains(sStringContains) = True) Then
```

Here's the function:

```
    Public Shared Function GetContains(ByVal sStringContains As String, ByVal customerDetail As String, ByVal oListOfCustomers As List(Of Customer))
    Dim oCustomerData As New CustomerData
    Dim oNewListOfCustomers As New List(Of Customer)
    Dim iIndex As Integer
    Dim oCustomer As Customer

    'Property Names: Company, Contact, City, State, Country, Zip, Status

    'Check for all properties. It works though.
    If IsNothing(oListOfCustomers) = False AndAlso oListOfCustomers.Count > 0 Then
            For iIndex = 0 To oListOfCustomers.Count - 1
                If (oListOfCustomers.Item(iIndex).Company.ToString.Trim.Contains(sStringContains) = True) Then

                    oCustomer = New Customer(oListOfCustomers.Item(iIndex).Company, oListOfCustomers.Item(iIndex).Contact, oListOfCustomers.Item(iIndex).Address1, oListOfCustomers.Item(iIndex).Address2, _
                                              oListOfCustomers.Item(iIndex).City, oListOfCustomers.Item(iIndex).State, oListOfCustomers.Item(iIndex).Country, oListOfCustomers.Item(iIndex).Zip, _
                                              oListOfCustomers.Item(iIndex).Zip4, oListOfCustomers.Item(iIndex).Email, oListOfCustomers.Item(iIndex).Phone, oListOfCustomers.Item(iIndex).Status, _
                                              oListOfCustomers.Item(iIndex).MasterContactID)

                    oNewListOfCustomers.Add(oCustomer)
                End If
            Next
    End If
    Return oNewListOfCustomers
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use reflection and `PropertyInfo.GetValue`. Try (untested):

```
Imports System.Reflection


Public Shared Function GetContains(ByVal sStringContains As String, ByVal customerDetail As String, ByVal oListOfCustomers As List(Of Customer))
    Dim oCustomerData As New CustomerData
    Dim oNewListOfCustomers As New List(Of Customer)
    Dim iIndex As Integer
    Dim oCustomer As Customer
    Dim propertyInfo As PropertyInfo

    'Property Names: Company, Contact, City, State, Country, Zip, Status
    'Get PropertyInfo for customerDetail-property
    propertyInfo = GetType(Customer).GetProperty(customerDetail)

    'Check for all properties. It works though.
    If IsNothing(oListOfCustomers) = False AndAlso oListOfCustomers.Count > 0 Then
        For iIndex = 0 To oListOfCustomers.Count - 1
            If (propertyInfo.GetValue(oListOfCustomers.Item(iIndex)).ToString.Trim.Contains(sStringContains) = True) Then

                oCustomer = New Customer(oListOfCustomers.Item(iIndex).Company, oListOfCustomers.Item(iIndex).Contact, oListOfCustomers.Item(iIndex).Address1, oListOfCustomers.Item(iIndex).Address2,
                                          oListOfCustomers.Item(iIndex).City, oListOfCustomers.Item(iIndex).State, oListOfCustomers.Item(iIndex).Country, oListOfCustomers.Item(iIndex).Zip,
                                          oListOfCustomers.Item(iIndex).Zip4, oListOfCustomers.Item(iIndex).Email, oListOfCustomers.Item(iIndex).Phone, oListOfCustomers.Item(iIndex).Status,
                                          oListOfCustomers.Item(iIndex).MasterContactID)

                oNewListOfCustomers.Add(oCustomer)
            End If
        Next
    End If
    Return oNewListOfCustomers
End Function
```